# How to set state when mocking a api call

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying my best to understand how to mock api calls and I've figured out you need to mock them using `jest.fn().mockImplementation()`:

But now I need to run this code and set the properties to the state so I can make sure that the call has updated the qty of the second item to three.

```
api.getCart = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({
    cart: mockCart,
    items: [{}, { qty: 3 }, {}],
}));
```

so in my test I have tested that the above is called which it is.

I would of expected this to have then set the state in my component function as that is what I'm doing below:

```
  /**
  * Fetchs the carts data.
  * Includes: Items, Totals and options.
  */
  getCartData() {
    const callCart = getCart(this.token);

    callCart.then((response) => {
      this.setState({
       cart: response,
       items: response.items,
      });
    });
  }
```

In my test I then want to write the below so that the test is equal to 3 instead of 2 (original value).

`expect(renderedCart.state().items[1].qty).toEqual(3);`

Comment: What does exactly not work? You omitted the rest of test and component files, while these pieces are important. More specifically, what's `api`, and where ` api.getCart = ...` occurs, and where `getCart` comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

You're close.  The `expect` fails before the `then` callbacks have a chance to run.

### Solution

Return the `Promise` created with `callCart.then` within `getCartData` and `await` the `Promise` in your test.  This will allow all the `then` callbacks to run and the state to change before the `expect` runs.

Here is a simplified working example based on the code snippets above:

---

api.js

```js
export const getCart = () => Promise.resolve(1);
```

---

code.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { getCart } from './api';

export class Comp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { qty: 2 };
  }
  getCartData() {
    const callCart = getCart(this.token);

    return callCart.then((response) => {   // return the Promise
      this.setState({
        qty: response
      });
    });
  }
  render() { return null; }
}
```

---

code.test.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import * as api from './api';
import { Comp } from './code';

test('Comp', async () => {   // make the test async
  api.getCart = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(3));

  const renderedCart = shallow(<Comp/>);
  await renderedCart.instance().getCartData();   // await the Promise
  expect(renderedCart.state().qty).toEqual(3);   // SUCCESS
});
```